# Is there a list of the most up voted questions?

Tags: feature-request

Looking for a list of questions with the most upvotes.  Like most up voted questions of the day, week, month, all time.

Does this exist?

Comment: The answers below provide a simple and efficient solution, which is probably what you were after. Alternatively, for more complex queries, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/queries), which allows you to create your own queries on the SE database, if you know a bit of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we do have a view for most upvoted.

Go to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions
Select the `votes` tab.
[image: votes tab]

This tab is available for search results too.  If you make an [advanced search](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) with time limits, and sort by votes, then you could find out the most upvoted of the week, month.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking on my phone and just didn't see the option deeper into the menu. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @DavidG25  It's a valid question.  Don't delete it, please.

Answer (score 2):

There is no static page with "questions of the month", etc. But such lists can be obtain with the site search, which supports [date range parameters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/searching). Examples:

- [Top questions of 2016](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a2016)
- [Top questions of July 2017](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aq+created%3A2017-07)
- [Top questions of January 20, 2017](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a2017-01-20)

The date range can also be relative:

- [Top questions of the last 7 days](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a7d..)
- [Top questions of the last year](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a1y..)

Also, the [tools](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tools) available to 10K users provide similar lists, but with less flexibility than the search (which doesn't require 10K reputation to use).